# Ordering by count of associated model Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sql-order-by, associated-object

I have two models:

jacket.rb:

```
  has_many :button
  belongs_to :store
```

button.rb:

```
belongs_to :jacket
```

In my store controller, I want to be able to do @store.jackets.order(buttons: :desc), but I cannot do this because it is not a db column. How would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some SQL in order to count the association, alias the count to a name, and order by that name:

```
@store.jackets.joins(:buttons).select("jackets.*, COUNT(buttons.id) as button_total").order('button_total DESC')
```

More on sql counts [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-count-function.htm)